# Visual Studio 2012 express installation - mscorpe.dll is not designed to run on Windows

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I try to install VS2012 express in  Windows 8, and encountered this error

[image]

> mscorpe.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Since your error is "C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorpe.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error", it seems .net framework 2.0 is corrupt on your OS.

.NET 2.0 is contained in .NET 3.5 and .NET 3.5 is actually a component of Win 8.

I would recommend you refer to this page first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx

Try enable .NET 3.5 on Win 8 first.

Then use this tool to verify .NET 2.0 and paste the result here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx

If it said .NET 2.0 is corrupt, refer to this page http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html use sfc /scannow to repair your Win 8.